# Poor video quality on Ubuntu 17.04 with Radeon HD Graphics Card

Tags: drivers, graphics, 17.04, radeon, amd-graphics

a few days ago I moved from Windows to Ubuntu (again) and I installed 17.04 on my Lenovo G50-80. Today as I was watching a video on my computer which supposed to be 720p I realized that something is wrong. Whenever there's a night scene, the video is blurry. Black or other dark colors are not good either.
Now as I understood after checking some articles, it may be a problem with my graphics card. I read that after 16.04 LTS Radeon is not supported or something like this.
I tried to find a solution online, but I couldn't. Is there any way to solve this by downloading drivers or updating them somehow?

Attached you can see a photo with my system, if it helps with anything. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first check what driver your system is currently using by running `lshw -c video` as root. The output should look like this:

```
  *-display
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 02
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

Take note of the value of `driver=`

Now run `modinfo <drivername>` and more details on the driver will be presented. You should be able to see if it's using the generic linux driver for AMD or if it's using a proprietary driver.

If it's using the generic Linux driver's then there is nothing we can do in terms of drivers, except if you want to compile and install the proprietary drivers and kernel yourself.

From my expereince working on a AMD and Linux system, best to work with VLC for video player.

Comment: So it gave me this: *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330 / M430]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       version: 83
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
And I tried to run modinfo <radeon> but it didn't work. Should I try to add something, radeon is not enough or it is not the name? I'm sorry for the lame question, I'm new to this.

Comment: It would be modinfo radeon

Comment: Yeah that the default AMD driver for linux, had exactly the same issue with AMD card last year. My final piece of advise would be to check under System Settings > Software and updates > Other drivers and see if they have any other options

Comment: I got this after running modinfo: /lib/modules/4.10.0-32-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/radeon/radeon.ko